# Laravel template with function?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently in the process of modernizing a legacy codebase and using Laravel.

The current infrastructure does something like this to print a value:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) {
    echo $row['value'];
}
```

All good...  Easy to do in Laravel.

Except, it then does something like this...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) {
    echo $row['value'];
    echo getValue($row['another_value']);
}
```

It calls another function to fetch the value each time in the loop and print the right value.

How can I replicate this or do the same thing without having a function in Laravel?

My code looks like this (blade's templating):

```
@foreach ($values as $value)
    <td> {{ $value->value }} </td>
@endforeach
```

And obviously, this doesn't work:

```
@foreach ($values as $value)
    <td> getValue({{ $value->value }}) </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from creating that helper function and using it in the view :)

Comment: {{ }} is an echo statement. If getValue exists, you should do ``{{ getValue($value->value) }}`` instead, with the echo statement surrounding all of it. Otherwise it's parsed as ``getValue(echo $value->value) }} `` which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
@foreach ($values as $value)
    <td> getValue({{ $value->value }}) </td>
@endforeach
```

Should be like this:

```
@foreach ($values as $value)
    <td>{{ getValue($value->value) }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Actually `{{ }}` print out anything (String) between those curly brackets, so `{{ getValue($value->value) }}` will be replaced with `<?php echo getValue($value->value) ?>`. Make sure that, your function returns a `string` value.

Comment: Completely irrelevant to my question.  It was answered by a comment.

Comment: @user3817533 How is his answer irrelevant, it answers exactly what you asked, and it's almost the same as Joel Hinz comment.